# Generating Forms in Django

Tags: django, forms, dynamic

I want to generate dynamic forms in django. Assume that I have a model that contains choices which consists of all fields of forms. If my user selects Textarea option and gives a label name, the form shoul display a textarea with given label. It could be a textinput, radiobutton etc.

So my model looks like :

```
TYPE_CHOICES = (
     (u'TextField',u'TextField'),
     (u'TextArea',u'TextArea'),
)

class SocietyForm(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    form_info = models.ForeignKey(FormInfo)


class FormInfo(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    form_info = models.ForeignKey(SocietyForm)
```

So far so good, however when it comes to generate widgets, well I have no idea here = )
I thought, if I generate a dictionary according to selected choice then I can assign it to the form's widget.

```
'''                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
def select_form_type(instance):                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    dict = {}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    if instance.content_type == "TextField":                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        dict.update({'%s'instance.label:forms.TextInput()})                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    else:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        dict.update({'%s'instance.label:forms.Textarea()})                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    return dict                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
'''

#class SocietyJoinForm(forms.ModelForm,instance):
```

But, SocietyJoinForm doen't recognize instance input. So any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to stumble upon your question looking at all the older ones. Let me know if you've already figured this out.

IMO, the easiest way would be to use Javascript. You wouldn't actually be able to change this in Django unless you created your own form object, in which case you'd most likely still have to use Javascript. You could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function display_form_obj(){
        var type_selection = document.getElementById('id_content_type');
        var label = document.getElementById('id_label');
        var dyn_obj = document.getElementById('id_dyn_obj_div');
        if( type_selection.value and label.value ){
            // Display the new object
            if( type_selection.value == 'TextField' ){
                dyn_obj.innerHTML = '<textarea ...>';  // Fill it with the info you need
            }
            else {
                dyn_obj.innerHTML = '<input type="text" ...>'; // Fill with needed info
            }
        }
        else {
            dyn_obj.innerHTML = '';
        }
    }

    function set_form_obj_events(){
        var type_selection = document.getElementById('id_content_type');
        var label = document.getElementById('id_label');
        if( label.addEventListener ){
            // Netscape, FF
            type_selection.addEventListener('change', display_form_obj, false);
            label.addEventListener('change', display_form_obj, false);
        }
        elif( label.attachEvent ){
            // IE
            type_selection.attachEvent('onchange', display_form_obj);
            label.attachEvent('onchange', display_form_obj);
        }
    }

</script>
...
<form ... onload="set_form_obj_events();">
    {{form.content_type}}
    {{form.label}}
    <div id="id_dyn_obj_div"></div>
    ...
</form>
```

Hope that helps.